# How to bind the Images in HTML page where the files are located inside WEB-INF\classes\uploads folder in tomcat server

Tags: java, jquery, html, tomcat

I am trying to use jQuery Scroller to a number of images stored in Java Web application.

I used `UPLOAD_PATH` to set upload folder for each images:

```
UPLOAD_PATH = this.getClass().getResource("/uploads").toURI()
                        .getPath();
```

These images are successfully saved and stored to this path.

During client binding I get JSON values as:

```
 [ {   "id" : "57b08900505ab53e40a97355",   "title" : "fdsafdasf",   "description" : "sfdfasd",   "rating" : 3,   "price" : 21.0,   "quantity" : 121,   "type" : "Road Bike",   "primaryimage" : "/uploads/1uSdodND_2016_08_14.jpg",   "addedon" : "2016-08-14",   "isactive" : true }, 
   {   "id" : "57b0318991ed7332c8dd67a3",   "title" : "fdsaf",   "description" : "fdsafd safdsaf",   "rating" : 4,   "price" : 32232.0,   "quantity" : 232,   "type" : "Mountain Bike",   "primaryimage" : "/uploads/rM1hHzek_2016_08_14.png",   "addedon" : "2016-08-14",   "isactive" : true } ]
```

I am trying to use simple HTML page to bind those images into a `<img>` tag but because images are actually stored in `WEB-INF\classes\uploads` I can not directly load those images into the page. Is there any simple way to load those JSON `primaryimage` field in a `HTML` page and display them.

Comment: Are you using any MVC framework like Spring or Struts?

Comment: No I am not using any particular framework. Is there any other way around to just grab that relative path to a simple HTML page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may write a simple Servlet and map the request to it. Sample code below:

**Servlet**

```
package com.javavirtues.sample;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String fileName = req.getPathInfo();
        InputStream resourceContent = getServletContext()
                .getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/classes/uploads" + fileName);
        if (resourceContent == null) {
            resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
        } else {
            OutputStream outputStream = resp.getOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            for (int length = 0; (length = resourceContent.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**web.xml snippet**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ImageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.javavirtues.sample.ImageServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <url-pattern>/uploads/*</url-pattern>
    <servlet-name>ImageServlet</servlet-name>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks! One simple change I did is the web.xml shows error when url-pattern is put before servlet-name so I just reverse that mapping this is working perfect!